# Internet Explorer triggering js hover immediately after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, hoverintent

I got a navigation menu that opens a submenu dropdown on hovering over the first level items. After a click on a first level link the mouse is on the same position on the new page .... so here's the thing:

On normal browsers (Firefox, Safari and Chrome) it triggers the hover effect only after the mouse moves.

On Internet Explorer it seems that the hover is triggered immediatly after load because the dropdown opens directly (which is pretty annoying). I even mapped the hover function in a mousemove but that doesn't change anything (does ie even trigger mousemove on load without even moving Oo).

Here the simplified code:

```
        jQuery( '#mainmenucontainer' ).hoverIntent( {

            over: function() {

                jQuery( 'body' ).addClass( 'mainmenu_active' );

            },
            out: function() {

                jQuery( 'body' ).removeClass( 'mainmenu_active' );

            }

        } );


        jQuery( '#mainmenu > ul > li' ).hoverIntent( {

            over: function() {

                jQuery( '#mainmenu > ul > li' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                jQuery( this ).addClass( 'active' );

            }
        } );
```

Comment: You appear to be adding the hoverIntent in response to every mousemouse. Was that you intention as you will wind up with 1000s of handlers attached after a few seconds of mouse movement? (note: I have not used hoverIntent, so maybe it does something different to usual plugins).

Comment: Hmm good point. No it wasn't. But it doesn't change anything without the mousemove. It was result of the problem ... The hoverIntent shouldn't behave other that the regular hover

Comment: That will need fixing too. You really need to provide a decent mockup of this (JSFiddle etc?) to allow for testing of solutions (and seeing the actual problem). Thanks.

Comment: Just look at: http://www.panoramahotel-oberjoch.com/ ;)

Comment: An example *we can edit*! :)